# Ler Arquivo remoto através de FTP com PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Olá, gostaria da ajuda dos senhores para solucionar o seguinte problema. E se possível me ajudar a entender o que ocorre

Código:

```
$FTP_HOST = "ftp.exemplo.com";
$FTP_USER = "usuario";
$FTP_PASS = "senha";

$cHandle = ftp_connect($FTP_HOST) or die("O Servidor não pode se conectar ao FTP");

$login_result = ftp_login($cHandle, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PASS) or die("O Servidor não pode logar-se no FTP!");

$user['Nome'] = 'ftp://usuario:senha@ftp.exemplo.com/diretorio/arquivo.ini'; //aqui está o meu problema.

if (!file_exists($user['Nome'])) {
     echo 'Arquivo Inexistente!';
} else
{
    echo 'Arquivo Existente!';
}
```

Bom, este é o código que deveria funcionar, porém não funciona. Se eu digitar no meu navegador: 
    ftp://usuario:senha@ftp.exemplo.com/diretorio/arquivo.ini
O arquivo abre e mostra os dados contidos nele. Se eu ultilizo no php ele nem se quer reconhece que o arquivo está lá, gostaria de saber de que forma posso resolver isto.

Para verificar se o arquivo existe eu poderia utilizar:

```
$cHandle = ftp_connect($FTP_HOST) or die("O Servidor não pode se conectar ao FTP");

$login_result = ftp_login($cHandle, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PASS) or die("O Servidor não pode logar-se no FTP!");
ftp_login($cHandle,"usuario","senha");

$dir = "/diretorio/";

$arq= "arquivo.ini";

$check_file_exist = $dir.$arq;

$contents_on_server = ftp_nlist($cHandle, $dir);

if (!in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server)) 
{
    echo 'Arquivo Inexistente';
}else 
{
    echo ' Arquivo Existente';
}
```

Funciona, só que nessa segunda forma, ele apenas verifica a existência do arquivo e eu gostaria de que ele além de verificasse abrisse o arquivo da forma como abriria na primeira opção, já pesquisei, fiz tentativas e não consegui então se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Então.. Como posso fazer o php abrir e ler o arquivo via ftp, da mesma forma que abre na primeira tentativa acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para abrir um arquivo existente em um servidor FTP, você precisaria ter ele localmente. Então você vai usar o PHP para baixar o arquivo do servidor.

```
$server = "endereco_do_servidor.com.br";
$FTP_HOST = "ftp.exemplo.com";
$FTP_USER = "usuario";
$FTP_PASS = "senha";
$cHandle = ftp_connect($FTP_HOST) or die("O Servidor não pode se conectar ao FTP");
$login_result = ftp_login($cHandle, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PASS) or die("O Servidor não pode logar-se no FTP!");
ftp_get($cHandle, "diretorio_destino/arquivo.ini", "diretorio_origem/arquivo.ini", FTP_BINARY);
```

Após isso o arquivo poderá ser aberto, só que localmente. Você pode direcionar o usuário para o endereço do arquivo.

```
header("Location: diretorio_destino/arquivo.ini")
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Mais dúvidas você pode tirar em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ftp.php